# error 'cc' exit status 1 when install pygsl in osx

Tags: python, clang, osx-yosemite, pygsl

I already have the gsl libraries and when I'm trying to install pygsl in my mac (OS X 10.10.3), I got 
(I'm posting only the last lines)

```
150 warnings and 10 errors generated.
error: Command "cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DSWIG_COBJECT_TYPES=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DPyGSL_SET_GSL_ERROR_HANDLER=1 -DNUMERIC=0 -UNDEBUG -I/Users/hawc/hawc_software/externals/2.01.01/External/gsl/1.15/include -IInclude -I. -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.12.0.dev0_1fc180b-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c testing/src/sf/sfmodule_testing.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/testing/src/sf/sfmodule_testing.o"
failed with exit status 1
```

The lines that indicate and error are

```
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1322:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_a_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e};
                                                 ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1322:79: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_a_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e};
                                                                              ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1328:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_b_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e};
                                                 ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1328:79: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_b_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_b_e};
                                                                              ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1343:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_se_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e};
                                                  ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1343:81: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_se_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_se_e};
                                                                                ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1349:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_Mc_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e};
                                                  ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1349:81: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_Mc_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Mc_e};
                                                                                ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1355:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_Ms_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e};
                                                  ^
testing/src/sf/sf__data.c:1355:81: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e'
static void * sf_mathieu_Ms_e_data [] = {(void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e, (void *) gsl_sf_mathieu_Ms_e};
```

I checked another answers for problems with 'cc' and they suggested to use

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

and then

```
sudo -E python setup.py install
```

But is not working

The cc version I have is:
`Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`

Comment: There isn't enough info from above to tell what your issue is. Basically it says "we called the compiler and it failed". You should try to find / post the actual errors as these will be more indicative of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my post

Comment: Looks like you're referencing GSL 1.15, this function `gsl_sf_mathieu_a_e` seems to show up in version 2(.1?). I suspect your gsl library is too old relative to pygsl.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe side-steps your question but on my mac I was easily able to install pygsl via the following method

```
brew install gsl
sudo easy_install pygsl
```